# How to show the full Image in Table view cell when we posted something Like Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tableview

This is My Code:

```
cell.ImageViewPost.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
cell.ImageViewPost.clipsToBounds = YES;
BaseURLIMG =[baseImageURl stringByAppendingString:[[ArrTotalResult valueForKey:@"post"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[cell.ImageViewPost setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLIMG] placeholderImage:nil];
```

My image is not showing as exactly cell frame. We need to show exactly like Facebook post, in which the posted image is showing in full view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that the imageViews frame is the size of the cell (or the size you want)
2. try changing the contentMode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`.
   If the image is still not the size you want then this will be because of the Height to width ratio of the image being different to that of the imageView so some cropping will occur. to stop this use `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`, which changes the aspect ratio of the image to match the imageView, but can distort the image.

Comment: hii..
if m using contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill then image is going to be stretch. but showing in full cell. but we have to show actual image . and it should not be stretchable

Comment: It is impossible to fill an imageView with an image with a different height to width ration than the imageView without some sort of stretching or cropping.

Comment: please give solution of this problem.i didnt find anyting yet